# Roslaunch: file not found error for logging

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosrun, logging, logger

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on a project, and I want to start the different nodes using a launch file. In the latter I start one Python node and the other is an rqt plugin that I created:

```
<launch>
    <node name="PiMaster_node" pkg="airplane_master" type="PiMaster.py" output="screen"/>
    <node name="airplane_master" pkg="airplane_master" type="airplane_master"/>
</launch>
```

My problem is that when I run the two scripts separately using `rosrun`, everything works perfectly, but when I use `roslaunch` to start my .launch file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/micdev/catkin_ws/devel/lib/airplane_master/PiMaster.py", line 15, in <module>
    exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)
  File "/home/micdev/catkin_ws/src/airplane_master/scripts/PiMaster.py", line 21, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(filename='src/airplane_master/src/airplane_master/Master.log', level=logging.ERROR,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1988, in basicConfig
    h = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1147, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1176, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/micdev/.ros/src/airplane_master/src/airplane_master/Master.log'
```

Basically it says that it couldn't find a Log file (that actually exists): I use the `logging` module in Python to log some infos in `Master.log` file... Maybe it is interacting with the ROS logger? If this is the case why doesn't it happen when I run the python file using rosrun?
Can someone help me, I'm stuck :(

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402402/roslaunch:-file-not-found-error-for-logging/) by [Mix_MicDev](https://answers.ros.org/users/100408/mix_micdev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/micdev/.ros/src/airplane_master/src/airplane_master/Master.log'
> ```

Note how the path is `/home/micdev/.ros/...`.

Is that where your log file is located?

Please note that when starting nodes using `roslaunch`, their *working directory* is set to `$ROS_HOME`, which in many cases is set to `$HOME/.ros`. In your case probably `/home/micdev/.ros`.

See #q235337, #q271442 and the linked Q&As there for more information.

Summarising: make sure you use absolute paths, not relative paths, or your scripts won't be able to find files they need.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mix_MicDev](https://answers.ros.org/users/100408/mix_micdev/) on 2022-06-16**:
Thank you for your answer! I am now using absolute paths like you said, and it's working.
Here's how I'm finding the path of the file inside the Python code:

```
file_name = os.path.join(rospkg.RosPack().get_path('package_name'), 'file_directory', 'file_name')
```

Just to make sure, that's what you meant by "absolute paths" right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-17**:
I would personally probably use a [param](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) as a child of the `node` and use [substitution args](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args) to have `roslaunch` construct the path for me. Your node would then just have to read the parameter from the parameter server.